# Deployment of published code?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment

I published the code with **Visual Studio 2010** and then deployed the pulished code on production server.

Everthing is working fine.

Suppose if I need to make some changes in code behind file (.cs file). Do I need to publish the code again and again from visual studio 2010?
Or Can I just need to replace the bin folder on production server?

Currenlty I publish the code each time I change the code in code behind file and replace the publish code on production server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bin directory will contain your compiled code so if that's all you change you can only deploy the bin folder.

But when you change other files, like your web.config, aspx, css or javascript files, those changes will not show up in your bin directory. Those physical files will need to be deployed.

Because deploying can be a tedious and repetitive process, it would be best to automate this. If you setup your webserver for [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy), you can automatically deploy from Visual Studio to your server. WebDeploy will keep track of all changes and make sure they are deployed.

Answer (score 1):

if you chage .cs files only, then you can replace dll files.

when you publish:

If you choose Replace matching files, it copies only changed files

it is equal to replace dll as above and also it is better option than doing it manually.

sometimes we may have changes css or javascripts but forgot to add them.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to modify the code behind code, you don't have to republish the whole project and just need to override the production files. Because it is a partial class of aspx page and is compiled at runtime.

But it is better to do it automatically using some tools. It can avoid human mistakes and run your test to make sure your change doesn't break any functions.